# VB.NET Merge multiple tables and then update MS Access db

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset

I am hitting an MS Access db with VB2005 and I am creating a table object like this

```
Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblCars WHERE WeekOf=#6/1/2011#"
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "CarData")
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
```

The table should have no rows since the data is brand new. I read a data text file with new data and pump this data into the table and add new rows like so:

```
'create a new empty row
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("CarData").NewRow()

'update the new row with fresh data
dsNewRow.Item("DriveDate") = dd
dsNewRow.Item("DCode") = dc
dsNewRow.Item("CarNum") = carID
'about 15 more fields

'add the filled row to the DataSet table
ds.Tables("CarData").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

'end loop

'update the database with the new rows
da.Update(ds, "CarData")
```

The table in the db has no primary keys but all this works and i get all my new data inserted into the Data table tblCars.

Now it so happens that I must also account for cars with no data. For that my plan was to get a list of cars from the control table and merge it with the Data table.

```
    Dim sSQL As String = "SELECT CarId FROM tblControlCars WHERE ActiveCar=True;"
    Dim daAct As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sSQL, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    daTail.Fill(ds, "ActCars")
    Dim cbAct As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daAct)
```

I then create my primary keys for the tables and then merge them.

```
    ds.Tables("CarData").Merge(ds.Tables("ActCars"))
```

This will give me a table with all the new data for cars that do have data and also a place holder for those cars that are active but did not get any data. However, when I try to do an update back to the db I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

I'm not sure I understand why the Merged data is not able to be pushed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before just add a primary key in your database table , the command builder needs a unique identification field to  generate  a proper command .
You can simply create a field called "id" and make auto-number then you don't have to update it manually and make it a primary key that's it